# UIColor in xcode 6.1 (extra argument in call)

Tags: xcode, swift, updates, uicolor

I recently update xcode from 6.0 to 6.1 and after the update I get an error regarding `UIColor`. The error says

`Extra argument 'blue' in call`. This problem did not exist in xcode 6.0.

Here's my code:

```
let texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: car.carType.spriteName).makeGlowWithColor(UIColor(red: 1, blue: 0, green: 1, alpha: 1)))
```

I've tried converting them to CGFloat etc without any success...

Comment: What is the function `makeGlowWithColor`? Is that your own function? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: `UIImage()` is now a failable initializer, thus it returns an optional. There are dozens of questions on SO regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitely unwrapp the optional value by adding **`!`**

```
UIColor(red: 1, blue: 0, green: 1, alpha: 1)!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you swapped `green` and `blue` parameter - the initializer looks like this: `init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)`. Does that work better?